# Does the snap package mean that we don't need to use super old softwares?

Tags: camera

Will elementary OS make lots of snap packages?

Does the snap package mean stable OS + new softwares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/

Please do refer to this link to have a better idea. I believe it's the new way, similar to windows where one can easily install applications. However the old ways are also going to stick around.

Answer (score 0):

Snaps means, that you can install Software, without installing dependencies, because all needed dependent software is already part of the snap-package.
All installed software coming from a snap is located in the filesystem under /snap unlike .deb packages, where it will be install allover the system.
Means you can also install different versions of the same software. For example /snap/firefox-49.0.2 /snap/firefox-49.03 /snap/firefox-50.0.1
So the installed software is only in that one specific folder and no where else in the filesystem.